# How would I go about drawing in a paint program with pressure sensitivity?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, tablet, system.drawing

I am writing a paint program of sorts, using C# .Net/WinForms and pressure sensitivity is a must. I have everything set up and am getting pressure information from the tablet pen. None of this is an issue.

What I am having trouble approaching is, how would I take your typical, simple paint program (i.e., 'Scribble') and draw using the pressure data I am getting? Scribble-type simple apps track current and previous cursor positions, while drawing is enabled, and draws lines between them. But each point laid down by capturing cursor positions is drawn between using a fixed width line.

Assuming I have all the data I need: x y positions and pen pressure, how would I begin to think about drawing between points that should be different widths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to keep track of the previous point and the previous size (based on pressure) and then draw a lineto from the previous point to the current point, using the previous size for the line size.

Even using GDI+ is fast this way, if you make sure not to create new objects in the event handler code.

The other way I mentioned is much more advanced (though may yield better results) and I may end up implementing it at a later date, when I do everything vector-based.

Comment: Isn't that what Cameronjchurch suggested? Seems kinda rude to make an answer which is the same as his answer and mark it as the answer. At least give reputation to the person who tried to help you

Comment: If that's what he meant, that's not how I understood him.

Answer (score 0):

I would break your total xy positions in to many smaller xy positions (maybe a pixel or two in length) and apply the width accordingly corresponding to the pen pressure.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, that would be a lot of calls to the GDI+ routines, which would slow things down a lot.

I thought about calculating the angles between points, and then bisecting these angles and setting a point on either side of the main point with distances corresponding to the pressure, and then drawing polygons using the two side points of the previous point and the two side points of the current point. This might involve recursion, I guess.

Comment: Yea, my suggestion would probably make for a lot of those calls. Good point.